# DAX HASONEVALUE row filter

Tags: dax, tabular

```
12 Total :=
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    HASONEVALUE ([level04] ), CALCULATE (
        [Local],
        DATESINPERIOD (
            Calendar[Date],
            MAX ( Calendar[Date] ),
            -12,
            MONTH
        )
    ),
    HASONEVALUE ([level03]),If([level 03]= "calculation:" && [level03]= "Cash:" && [level03]= "Costs:"=>0, Blank(), CALCULATE (
        [Local],
        DATESINPERIOD (
            Calendar[Date],
            MAX ( Calendar[Date] ),
            -12,
            MONTH
        )
)
        ),
        HASONEVALUE ( [level02] ), BLANK ()
    )
```

I would like to add condition that if lever 03 = cash, calculation, and cost then return blank to remove sub total rows. I tried something like that and its not working properly it gives me error "value for column level03 cannot be determined in the current context". how can i add that condition in level03 column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a side note, "its not working properly" is tremendously unhelpful in determining the source of problems. Specifically in a Power Pivot/Tabular model, [this link provides a list of ways to help answerers help you](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28212.how-to-ask-a-power-pivot-question-to-get-a-prompt-accurate-and-helpful-response.aspx).

Syntactically, there are some errors. Let's address those and see if the behavior is appropriate before diving into alternate measure definitions.

This section is the problem:

```
...
,HASONEVALUE([level03])
    // Note, you are inconsistent in referring to [level03] and
    // [level 03]
,If( // Below you are testing column references against scalar
     // literals. DAX doesn't understand how to do this, so you
     // have to wrap each reference in a VALUES() function, which
     // can be implicitly converted to a scalar value
    [level 03] = 'calculation:'   // DAX needs double quotes: ""
        && [level03]= 'Cash:'     // You have multiple predicates
        && [level03]=' Costs:'=>0 // for a single field combined
                                  // with a logical and - these
                                  // can't all simultaneously be true
    ,Blank()
    ,CALCULATE(
        [Local]
        ,DATESINPERIOD(
            Calendar[Date],
            MAX ( Calendar[Date] ),
            -12,
            MONTH
        )
    )
)
,....
```

I am just going to change the combination of predicates to a logical or in my rewrite, so that it's possible for this IF() to return a BLANK. The way it's written above, even fixing the syntax errors will cause it to always evaluate the else condition, because [level 03] cannot simultaneously have the value of "calculation:", "Cash:", and " Costs:=>0".

```
...
,HASONEVALUE('<table>'[level03]) 
    // As a best practice, you should always use fully qualified
    // column references - 'table'[field]
    // Also, I've referred only to [level03] below
,IF( // Note we've wrapped [level 03] in VALUES() below - this will
     // allow our comparisons to scalar literals
    VALUES('<table>'[level03]) = "calculation:" // double quotes
        || VALUES('<table>'[level03]) = "Cash:"  
            // Note: we've changed the logical and, &&, to a logical
            // or, || - meaning if any 1 of these predicates is true,
            // we'll return BLANK
        || VALUES('<table>'[level03]) = " Costs:=>0"
    ,BLANK()
    ,CALCULATE(
        [Local]
        ,DATESINPERIOD(
            Calendar[Date]
            ,MAX( Calendar[Date] )
            ,-12
            ,MONTH
        )
    )
)
,....
```

What this will do is check for any cell on the pivot table where [level03] has exactly one distinct value - when this is true, it will evaluate the IF() function.

The IF() function will check the value of [level03]. If that value is any one of the three following values, "calculation:", "Cash:", or " Costs:=>0", it will return BLANK. If the value of [level03] is not any of those three, it will evaluate the CALCULATE(), which returns the measure [Local] for a rolling 12 month period.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never thought of values functions thanks!